# 'child == _child': is not true , Duplicate GlobalKey detected in widget tree

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I am getting this error when I render a child component in flutter.

- **Failed assertion: line 6075 pos 12: 'child == _child': is not true.**
- **Duplicate GlobalKey detected in widget tree.**
- **A RenderShrinkWrappingViewport expected a child of type RenderSliver but received a child of type RenderFlex.**

my code is here.........

```js
// @dart=2.9

import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_project/constants.dart';
import 'package:flutter_project/provider/store_provider.dart';
import 'package:flutter_project/services/store_services.dart';
import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';
import 'package:paginate_firestore/bloc/pagination_listeners.dart';
import 'package:paginate_firestore/paginate_firestore.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

class NearByStore extends StatefulWidget {


  @override
  _NearByStoreState createState() => _NearByStoreState();
}

class _NearByStoreState extends State<NearByStore> {
  StoreServices _storeServices = StoreServices();

  PaginateRefreshedChangeListener refreshedChangeListener = PaginateRefreshedChangeListener();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final _storeData = Provider.of<StoreProvider>(context);
    _storeData.getUserLocationData(context);


    String getDistance(location) {
      var distance = Geolocator.distanceBetween(
          _storeData.userLatitude, _storeData.userLongitude, location.latitude,
          location.longitude);
      var distanceInKm = distance / 1000;
      return distanceInKm.toStringAsFixed(2);
    }

    return Container(
      child: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
        stream: _storeServices.getTopPickedStore(), // will change it soon
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot>snapShot) {
          if (!snapShot.hasData) return
            CircularProgressIndicator();
          List shopDistance = [];
          for (int i = 0; i <= snapShot.data.docs.length - 1; i++) {
            var distance = Geolocator.distanceBetween(
                _storeData.userLatitude, _storeData.userLongitude,
                snapShot.data.docs[i]['location'].latitude,
                snapShot.data.docs[i]['location'].longitude);
            var distanceInKm = distance / 1000;
            shopDistance.add(distanceInKm);
          }
          shopDistance
              .sort(); // this will sort with nearest distance. if nearest distance is more than 10, that means no shop near by;
          if (shopDistance[0] > 10) {
            return Container(
              child: Stack(
                children: [
                  Center(
                    child: Text('***That all folks***',
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),),
                  ),
                  Image.asset(
                      'images/city.png', color: Colors.black12),
                  Positioned(
                    right: 10.0,
                    top: 80,
                    child: Container(
                      width: 100,
                      child: Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: [
                          Text('Made by : ', style: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.black54
                          ),),
                          Text('VOID TECHNOLOGY', style: TextStyle(
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              fontFamily: 'Anton',
                              letterSpacing: 2,
                              color: Colors.grey
                          ),)
                        ],

                      ),
                    ),
                  )

                ],
              ),
            );
          }
          return Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                RefreshIndicator(
                  child: PaginateFirestore(
                    bottomLoader: CircularProgressIndicator(
                      valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(Theme
                          .of(context)
                          .primaryColor),
                    ),
                    header: Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: [
                        Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                              left: 8, right: 8, top: 20
                          ),
                          child: Text('All Nearby Stores',
                            style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w900,
                                fontSize: 18
                            ),),
                        ),

                        Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                              left: 8, right: 8, bottom: 10
                          ),
                          child: Text('Findout quality products near you',
                            style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 12, color: Colors.grey
                            ),),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                    shrinkWrap: true,
                    physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                    itemBuilderType: PaginateBuilderType.listView,
                    itemBuilder: (index, context, document) =>
                        Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4),
                          child: Container(
                            width: MediaQuery
                                .of(context)
                                .size
                                .width,
                            child: Row(
                              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                              children: [
                                SizedBox(
                                  width: 100,
                                  height: 110,
                                  child: Card(
                                    child: ClipRRect(
                                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4),
                                      child: Image.network(document['imageUrl'],
                                        fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                                SizedBox(width: 10,),
                                Column(
                                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                  children: [
                                    Container(
                                      child: Text(
                                        document['shopName'], style: TextStyle(
                                        fontSize: 14,
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                      ),
                                        maxLines: 2,
                                        overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    SizedBox(
                                      height: 3,
                                    ),
                                    Text(document['dialog'],
                                      style: kStoreCardStyle,),
                                    SizedBox(
                                      height: 3,
                                    ),
                                    Container(
                                      width: MediaQuery
                                          .of(context)
                                          .size
                                          .width - 250,
                                      child: Text(document['address'],
                                        overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                        style: kStoreCardStyle,
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    SizedBox(
                                      height: 3,
                                    ),
                                    Text(
                                      '${getDistance(document['location'])}Km',
                                      overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                    ),
                                    SizedBox(
                                      height: 3,
                                    ),
                                    Row(
                                      children: [
                                        Icon(
                                          Icons.star,
                                          size: 12,
                                          color: Colors.grey,
                                        ),
                                        SizedBox(
                                          width: 4,
                                        ),
                                        Text('3.2', style: kStoreCardStyle,)
                                      ],
                                    )

                                  ],
                                )

                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                    query: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('vendors')
                        .where('accVerified', isEqualTo: true)
                        .where('isTopPicked', isEqualTo: true).orderBy(
                        'shopName'),
                    listeners: [
                      refreshedChangeListener,
                    ],
                    footer: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 30),
                      child: Container(
                        child: Stack(
                          children: [
                            Center(
                              child: Text('***That all folks***',
                                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),),
                            ),
                            Image.asset(
                                'images/city.png', color: Colors.black12),
                            Positioned(
                              right: 10.0,
                              top: 80,
                              child: Container(
                                width: 100,
                                child: Column(
                                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                  children: [
                                    Text('Made by : ', style: TextStyle(
                                        color: Colors.black54
                                    ),),
                                    Text('VOID TECHNOLOGY', style: TextStyle(
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                        fontFamily: 'Anton',
                                        letterSpacing: 2,
                                        color: Colors.grey
                                    ),)
                                  ],

                                ),
                              ),
                            )

                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),

                  ),

                  onRefresh: () async {
                    refreshedChangeListener.refreshed = true;
                  },
                )
              ],

            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

```
    ======== Exception caught by widgets library =======================================================
The following assertion was thrown building RawGestureDetector-[LabeledGlobalKey<RawGestureDetectorState>#a5a30](state: RawGestureDetectorState#b8caf(gestures: <none>, behavior: opaque)):
'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart': Failed assertion: line 6075 pos 12: 'child == _child': is not true.


Either the assertion indicates an error in the framework itself, or we should provide substantially more information in this error message to help you determine and fix the underlying cause.
In either case, please report this assertion by filing a bug on GitHub:
  https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/new?template=2_bug.md

The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  PaginateFirestore file:///E:/Flutter%20Main/flutter_project/lib/widgets/near_by_store.dart:99:26
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#2      SingleChildRenderObjectElement.forgetChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6075:12)
#3      Element._retakeInactiveElement (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3563:14)
...     Normal element mounting (10 frames)
#13     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3611:14)
#14     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3360:20)

======== Exception caught by widgets library =======================================================
The following assertion was thrown while finalizing the widget tree:
Duplicate GlobalKey detected in widget tree.

The following GlobalKey was specified multiple times in the widget tree. This will lead to parts of the widget tree being truncated unexpectedly, because the second time a key is seen, the previous instance is moved to the new location. The key was:
- [GlobalKey#4acc7]
This was determined by noticing that after the widget with the above global key was moved out of its previous parent, that previous parent never updated during this frame, meaning that it either did not update at all or updated before the widget was moved, in either case implying that it still thinks that it should have a child with that global key.
The specific parent that did not update after having one or more children forcibly removed due to GlobalKey reparenting is:
- Semantics(container: false, properties: SemanticsProperties, label: null, value: null, hint: null, hintOverrides: null, renderObject: RenderSemanticsAnnotations#faf5c NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE DETACHED)
A GlobalKey can only be specified on one widget at a time in the widget tree.
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#0      BuildOwner.finalizeTree.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2900:15)
#1      BuildOwner.finalizeTree (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2925:8)
#2      WidgetsBinding.drawFrame (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:877:19)
#3      SchedulerBinding._invokeFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1144:15)
#4      SchedulerBinding.handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1082:9)
...
====================================================================================================
```

Answer (score 0):

The `header` and `footer` properties are expected to be Slivers. so in order to use non-sliver widgets, you can wrap them with SliverToBoxAdapter which is "a sliver that contains a single box widget."
**Try like this.**
Update the `Header` code to:

```
header: SliverToBoxAdapter(
  child: Column(
    ...
  ),
),
```

And update the `footer` code to:

```
footer: SliverToBoxAdapter(
  child: Padding(
    ...
  )
),
```