# A RenderShrinkWrappingViewport expected a child of type RenderSliver but received a child of type RenderFlex

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-sliver

i am new in flutter and firebase integration. i am trying to build mobile app that connect to firestore.

i am trying to use paginate firestore in my mobile app. But i got error message that said "A RenderShrinkWrappingViewport expected a child of type RenderSliver but received a child of type RenderFlex."

this is my code

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Container(
  child: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
    stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('vendors')
        .orderBy('shopName').snapshots(),
    builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapShot) {
      if (snapShot.data == null) return CircularProgressIndicator();
      if(snapShot.hasData){
        print("error");
      }
      return Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            RefreshIndicator(
              child: PaginateFirestore(
                bottomLoader: CircularProgressIndicator(
                  valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(
                      Theme.of(context).primaryColor),
                ),
                header: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    Padding(
                      padding:
                          const EdgeInsets.only(left: 8, right: 8, top: 20),
                      child: Text(
                        'All Nearby Stores',
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w900, fontSize: 18),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Padding(
                      padding:
                          const EdgeInsets.only(left: 8, right: 8, top: 20),
                      child: Text(
                        'Find quality products near you',
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w900,
                            fontSize: 12,
                            color: Colors.grey),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                shrinkWrap: true,
                physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                itemBuilderType: PaginateBuilderType.listView,
                itemBuilder: (index, context, document) => Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4),
                  child: Container(
                    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                    child: Row(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: [
                        SizedBox(
                          width: 120,
                          height: 100,
                          child: Card(
                            child: ClipRRect(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4),
                              child: Image.network(
                                document['imageUrl'],
                                fit: BoxFit.fill,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          width: 10,
                        ),
                        Column(
                          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: [
                            Container(
                              height: 35,
                              child: Text(
                                document['shopName'],
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 14,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                ),
                                maxLines: 2,
                                overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                              ),
                            ),
                            SizedBox(
                              height: 3,
                            ),
                            Container(
                                width:
                                    MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - 250,
                                child: Text(
                                  document['location'],
                                  overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      fontSize: 14,
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                                )),
                            SizedBox(
                              height: 3,
                            ),
                            Row(
                              children: [
                                Icon(
                                  Icons.star,
                                  size: 12,
                                  color: Colors.grey,
                                ),
                                SizedBox(
                                  width: 4,
                                ),
                                Text(
                                  '3.2',
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 10,
                                  ),
                                )
                              ],
                            )
                          ],
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                query: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                    .collection('vendors')
                    .orderBy('shopName'),
                listeners: [
                  refreshChangeListener,
                ],
                footer: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 30),
                  child: Container(
                    child: Stack(
                      children: [
                        Center(
                          child: Text(
                            "that's al folks",
                            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Image.asset(
                          "image/city.png",
                        ),
                        Positioned(
                            right: 10,
                            top: 80,
                            child: Container(
                              width: 100,
                              child: Column(
                                crossAxisAlignment:
                                    CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                children: [
                                  Text(
                                    'Made By : ',
                                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                                  ),
                                  Text(
                                    "IZZILLY TEAM",
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                        letterSpacing: 2,
                                        color: Colors.grey),
                                  )
                                ],
                              ),
                            ))
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              onRefresh: ()async{
                refreshChangeListener.refreshed = true;
              },
            )
          ],
        ),
      );
    },
  ),
);
}
```

does anyone know how to solve this error?

thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to related issues, something that your code should do is to wrap the header and footer widgets (and other box type widgets) inside a [SliverToBoxAdapter](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SliverToBoxAdapter-class.html). You can refer to this other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67998846/16929894) and this [Github issue](https://github.com/vedartm/pagination_view/issues/44) to see sample code which resemble yours. Wrapping your header, for example, would look like this according to the related question:

```
header: SliverToBoxAdapter(
  child: Column(
    ...
  ),
),
```

You should also attach logs and error details in your question like those present in the github issue and related question I linked. It would shine more light into the details leading to the error.